# g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0’ running gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, g++

I'm not sure exactly what is causing this error when running `gem install jekyll`.

I'm running:

```
  Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.09
  Gem 2.6.14
  ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
  g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because of the gcc version. It is used to suppress all warnings and it is there in version 7. Maybe not before. You can try and update them.

You can search and see that command line option isn't there, in version 4.8.5
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Option-Index.html#Option-Index

But it is there in  7.1
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Option-Index.html#Option-Index_op_letter-W

Here is a guide which I found to install ruby and its niceties   in AMI
http://www.jonathanhui.com/install-ruby-rubygems-ruby-rails-3-amazon-linux

Comment: yeah, I'm not sure exactly. I ended up upgrading the instance to an Amazon Linux 2 instance and running everything as root and that seemed to work. It could be linked to the version of gcc on Amazon Linux 1.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was a tad bit different but merits documenting somewhere.
I had Cuda 10 installed which seems to have its own copy of GCC in there (`which gcc` will show you which one you're using)